# Supporting Multiple Screens - usage of <compatible-screens>

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, screen-density

I am having hard time understanding how to make my app available on certain devices but exclude other devices. I have Acer Iconia One 7 B1. Screen 7", 800x1280 pixels and 216 ppi density. At the first release of my app, Google Play said it was not compatible with my tablet. This was my manifest at the beginning:

```
<compatible-screens>
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi"  android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi"  android:screenSize="normal"/>
        <screen android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" android:screenSize="normal"/>
        <!-- mdpi and hdpi large size screens -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi"  android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi"  android:screenSize="large" />
        <!-- mdpi x-large size screens -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi"  android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25"
        />
```

After researching, I found out that my tablet had tvdpi density so I added few more lines to the Manifest to include ALL normal size screens:

```
<screen   android:screenSize="normal"  android:screenDensity="213"/>
<screen   android:screenSize="normal"  android:screenDensity="420"/>
<screen   android:screenSize="normal"  android:screenDensity="560"/>
<screen   android:screenSize="normal"  android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"/>
<!-- to exclude TVs -->
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"   
                    android:required="true"/>
```

When I was uploading version 2 of my app, the Google console showed me a warning that the **updated apk supports LESS devices than the version 1 despite me adding more compatible screens!!!** 
Please help me understand what am I doing wrong? Basically, I need to support all possible normal screen sizes no matter the density; large MDPI and HDPI and also extra large MDPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this for two days (shame on me for taking this long), I looked into the AVD manager in Android Studio to find out that the Nexus 7, which has the same specs as my Acer Iconia, is considered Large, not Normal. 
Once I changed the

```
<screen   android:screenSize="normal"  android:screenDensity="213"/>
```

to:

```
<screen   android:screenSize="large"  android:screenDensity="213"/>
```

and uploaded the new APK to the Play Store, my tablet was finally compatible with the app. I hope this helps somebody someday when they cant figure out why their tvdpi tablet is deemed not compatible with their app.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for excluding TV is my guess for the culprit, TV apps can only be supported by using the Leanback Intent library (which is disabled by default).

By forcing touchscreen you are eliminating only a few devices (including those cheap android TV boxes that run the phone version of android)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you shouldn't be using `<compatible-screens>` at all.

From the documentation:

> **Caution**: Normally, **you should not use this manifest element**. Using this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your application, by not allowing users to install your application if they have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed. You should use it only as a last resort, when the application absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations.

You say "I need to support all possible normal screen sizes no matter the density". If this means that you must *exclude* `small` screen sizes, you can use the `<supports-screens>` element instead. Something like

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"/>
```

Comment: I considered this but then I also have to exclude large XHDPI + XXHDPI and also have to exclude X-large HDPI, XHDPI and XXHDPI... I did read the docs regarding the <compatible-screens> but then there is no other option when it comes to special cases when some screen sizes with certain density have to be included but others excluded.

Comment: Why do you have to exclude these? I ask because I find that, often, developers new to Android think about screens in very rigid terms... and frequently the right "answer" is just to stop worrying so much about what happens if someone with a big phone gets your app.

Comment: I am using SurfaceView with a lot of graphics which look small of very large phones/tablets. I provided just about enough drawables to cover the normal screens and they look somewhat OK on bigger screens but not on all.